# How to scroll to an element with appium using webdriveriO

Tags: appium-ios

I am using following command:
  browser.scroll('#login');

I am getting this error - Not yet implemented. Please help us: http://appium.io/get-involved.html

Answer (score 0):

```
public void scroll()
    {
        Dimension dimensions = driver.manage().window().getSize();  
        System.out.println(dimensions);

        Double screenHeightStart = dimensions.getHeight() * 0.5;
        int scrollStart = screenHeightStart.intValue();

        Double screenHeightEnd = dimensions.getHeight() * 0.2;
        int scrollEnd = screenHeightEnd.intValue();

        ((IOSDriver<MobileElement>) driver).swipe(0, scrollStart, 0, scrollEnd, 1000);  
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this command:

```
browser.execute("mobile: scroll", {direction: 'down'});
```

Answer (score 0):

For IOS: `browser.execute("mobile: scroll", {direction: 'down'});`
For Android I've tried so many ways myself but did not get any robust result.

Answer (score 0):

for Android device the next command helped me:

> driver.execute("mobile: scroll", { 'strategy': '-android uiautomator',
> 'selector': element })

Comment: But this question is tagged for iOS. You're answering a question that wasn't asked here.